# What is the largest cassette I can fit on a Canyon Grizl CF SL 7 1by?

Tags: cassette, drivetrain, replacement

I'm considering buying a [Canyon Grizl CF 7 1by](https://www.canyon.com/en-us/gravel-bikes/bike-packing/grizl/cf-sl/grizl-cf-sl-7-1by/2849.html), but I do a lot of bikepacking in hilly areas, so I'd like to put on a larger cassette to lower the minimum gear ratio. What is the largest cassette that I can fit on that bike? If I use something like the [Wolf Tooth Road Link](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/products/roadlink), can I fit an even larger cassette?

Editor’s note: the bike has Shimano GRX 11s, and the [stated](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/RD-RX812.html) max tooth count for the RD RX812 is 42t.

Comment: Note you can also sacrifice top end speed for globally lower Gera ratios with a smaller chainrings (dependent on crank design)

Comment: Good point! Do you know what the smallest chainring I could put on it is?

Comment: A arguably better solution for your use case is a 2x drive train. If you drill though the marketing, the main advantages of1x comes from frame design limitations of full suspension, simpler, therefore costed down assembly helps manufacturers push the system.   2x is still relevant, Worth a read.. https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/product-news/gravel-bike-gearing-should-you-run-1x-or-2x-463457

Answer (score 1):

Bikepacking has published [an article](https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/) on this topic. Short version: big cassettes require MTB derailleurs, that are not compatible with road/gravel brifters (except electronic ones). There are mostly workarounds, not many factory approved solutions.

There's a version of the Goat Link that works with the GRX and let you use a 11/50 cassette. My personnal experience with a deviation of 6 teeth on the big sprocket size is a seriously degraded shifting performance on the smaller sprockets (that will be 8 teeth).

If you want a "factory approved" solution, the easiest solution, that is not mentioned in the article, is using an electronic transmission (there's a version of the Grizl with an EXPLR drivetrain, not much more expensive that the one you mentioned, but without dropper post). Then you can replace the derailleur by an Eagle AXS, that will allow you to replace the 10/44 cassette by a 10/52 one. That being said, it may be less necessary given this version has a wider range the one you linked to (440% vs 380%). It's not cheap though: you'll need to replace the chain, the derailleur and the cassette. But at least, there won't be any other change on the drivetrain.

Note that you can also buy the frame of the Grizl separately (note sure it will be cheaper though, and procuring components these days can be challenging), and some brands are offering a version of their bike directly fitted with the Eagle derailleur (Cube Nuroad C:62 SL for instance, but this bike is also hard to find).